# How to parse json array with Retrofit and RxJava

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have problem parsing array of objects using Retrofit + RxJava

JSON contains only this array

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "notificationId": 15,
            "name": "cats.ncs",
            "dateTime": "2019-01-07T17:34:45"
        }
    ]
}
```

retrotfit service

```
@GET("/api/FileApi/files")
fun files(): Observable<FilesResponse>
```

where FilesResponse is

```
data class FilesResponse(
    @SerializedName("files")
    var files: List<FileElement>
)
```

and FileElement

```
data class FileElement(
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Long,
    @SerializedName("notificationId")
    var notificationId: Long,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("dateTime")
    var dateTime: String
)
```

when I run it I get always

> the return type of CallObjectMethodA does not match
>   io.reactivex.Observable ApiService.files()

So how do I parse JSON containing only an array?

Comment: Show how you are calling it

Answer (score 1):

Try using [RxJava2 Adapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2)

**Integration**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:{retrofit_version}'
```

**Retrofit client setup**

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) //option 1
  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.newThread())) //option 2
  .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few notes**

First of, you might need to show us how you call `ApiService.files()`

**What could possibly went wrong**

How it is called

**What could be the possible solution**

Invoke the method like this

```
ApiService
        .files()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            // Handle the values here
        },{
            // Handle the error here
        },{
            // Handle the completion here (optional)
        })
```

Not like this

```
ApiServices.files()
```

nor

```
var fileResponse = ApiServices.files()
```

Ensure the you have setup your retrofit builder well, as mentioned above

- RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
- GsonConverterFactory

Other than that, without the code on how you call it, we won't be able to help you in an in-depth manner.